# Xdebug PHP from remote linux server to Mac OS X DGBp client

Tags: php, linux, macos, xdebug

I am trying to set up an XDebug connection on a remote linux server to my local IDE (PHPStorm) running on Mac OS X. PHP just hangs forever trying to connect. I'm pretty sure this is a matter of making my Mac accessible to the linux box. I'm quite familiar with how to set up XDebug with PHPStorm and I've read the other posts here and elsewhere on the subject. What I need I think is some way to test the DGBp connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of xdebug.remote_mode? You an set it to "req" to always try to connect to a remote debugger. Also, you can enable xdebug logging via this setting: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_log - set it to /tmp/xdebug.log or similar on the linux box where the php is running, and restart apache - it should tell you what's happening.